# Sencha Touch ios 11

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, background-image, tabbar

I have a Cordova application with Sencha Touch framework which contains a tabpanel with custom background images.These images are working perfectly fine in ios 9 and ios 10 but in ios 11 these images doesn't show up.I have tried upgrading cordova plugins but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you debug in safari dev tools ? There must be an error if images cannot be loaded, and that error message will make you fix it.

Comment: I couldn't find any error message.Though I found out that the visibility is set to hidden for images in iOS 11.That's strange because when I run the same code in previous versions images are visible only in iOS 11 it is set to hidden.